# C++ addon works fine in nodev0.8.18 but does not work in nodev0.12.2

Tags: .net, node.js, visual-c++

I have a c++ addon which is using managed code and which works fine with nodev0.8.18. Now I am trying to upgrade my node to 0.12.2. I have rebuilt nodev0.12.2 and also C++ addon. The addon is built fine, but when I call the addon I get the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library popup screen which says -

"R6033 - Attempt to use MSIL code from this assembly during native code initialization. This indicates a bug in your application. It is most likely the result of calling as MSIL - compiled (/clr) function from a native constructor or from DllMain".

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obviously a problem with the entry point of the .node and the managed state of .node/.dll.

You could try to "unmanaged" the entry point with something like:

## pragma managed(push, off)

NODE_MODULE(myconnector, InitAll)

## pragma managed(pop)

NODE_MODULE is basically the macro that define the dllmain, and the macro I gave will ask VS to define the dll as not managed. The rest of your application will stay managed.